# How do I change the code from using Google.GData.Client to Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2

Tags: vb.net, google-api-dotnet-client, google-oauth

I have this code from obsolete dll's,
It works, but I know there are new dll's Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2 - Can I still use it?

```
      Public sub Activate
            _parameters = New Google.GData.Client.OAuth2Parameters With {
                .ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
                .ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET,
                .RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URL,
                .Scope = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/ ",
                .State = "documents",
                .AccessType = "offline"
            }

            Dim url As String = Google.GData.Client.OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(_parameters)

            context.WebRoot.Response.Redirect(url, False)
      End Sub

      Public Sub CallBack()
            Dim state As String = context.WebRoot.Request.QueryString("state")
            If Not state Is Nothing Then
                  _parameters.AccessCode = .WebRoot.Request.QueryString("code")
                  Google.GData.Client.OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(_parameters)
            End If
      End Sub
```

Comment: which api are you trying to access?   Google Docs?

Comment: Now I'm accessing Drive, it was Google Docs before

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/ is quite different you are going to have to change your code.   the main problem is you are using GData librarys its just not the same anymore

Comment: After the authorization/authentication I manage to access the Drive and retrieve files and directories.... just the auth is still as before

Comment: What is your problem then?

Comment: Can I still use the code above - without getting notification again that I need to change it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "without getting notification again that I need to change it"

Comment: :-) I get notify that oauth1 is deprecated, that was 1 year ago approx so I changed the code to work with oauth2 via Google.GData dll's, than I get notify that the new oauth2 dll's are Google.Apis and not Google.GData, it is still working - (the code above) - I just needed to use Google.Apis.Drive.v2 for accessing Drive - so my question is do I need to change the code above - which is oauth2 just not with the new  Google.Apis dll's?  thats all....

Comment: If you want to use Google.apis.drive.v2  which is smart and you should do.  You need to change all of that code stop using Google.Gdata .  While you could probably mix them I wouldn't want to try and do it.

Comment: So my question about Google.apis.drive.v2, when I have refresh_token than I just pass it and get access - my problem is when I need to activate (receive refresh_token) - I can do it with HttpContext - but, is there better and easier way to do it by Google.apis.drive.v2 ?

Comment: Client lib should handle all that for you. If you have a bunch of refresh tokens just make your own implementation of Idatastore to load them.   by default system uses FileDataStore  This is the only VB example I can find.  https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp/Program.vb?repo=samples  All I have is C# examples

Comment: C# would be great also, Thanks!

Comment: http://www.daimto.com/category/googledrive/  https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Drive https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Authentication   My VB .net is very out of date so I cant be much help with that.